# My challenges,Joomla Administrator www.melhevconcept.com/administrator

Tags: plugin

My challenges>>>> JAuthentication: :authenticate: Failed to load plugin: plgauthenticationcookie
JAuthentication: :authenticate: Failed to load plugin: plgauthenticationplg_simplemembership_authentication
Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.

Comment: Please provide more detailed information. http://joomla.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

please look for the name as "plg_authentication_joomla" on #__extensions table and set the column "enabled" to 1 if it set 0. and also do the same for  name as "plg_user_Joomla" .